# Database error 1054 after upgrade to ee 2.11.6

Tags: ee2, error, database, upgrade, sessions

A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'fingerprint' in 'field list'

SELECT `member_id`, `admin_sess`, `fingerprint`, `sess_start`, `login_state`, `last_activity` FROM (`exp_sessions`) WHERE `session_id` = '61d62d6d1f526c3ea67c9561cbef791a470a7101' AND `fingerprint` = ''

Filename: libraries/Session.php

Line Number: 731

**Does anyone know how I can fix this issue?  Please?  Thank you!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Fingerprint field" is missing in DB.

Go to Database to trigger this query.

```
ALTER TABLE  `exp_sessions` ADD  `fingerprint` VARCHAR( 40 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL AFTER  `user_agent`
```